# Is there a way to convert a JSON Schema to an XSD?

Tags: java, json, xml, xsd, type-conversion

I am currently looking for a way to convert a JSON Schema to an XSD or XML schema. I have found nothing on this topic and was hoping maybe someone here knew. I was hoping to do it with the Java APIs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Jsons2xsd](https://github.com/ethlo/jsons2xsd) converts [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) to [XML Schema](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/) (XSD) and is Java based.