# Generate XML schema(XSD) from JSON schema

Tags: xml, xsd, transform, jsonschema

Does anybody know how to generate a XML schema(XSD file) from an existing JSON schema?  Are there any tools available for this? On-line tools are preferred, I have found a free trial tool called Altova. THX.

Comment: Google? https://www.google.com/search?q=json+to+xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139862/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-json-schema-to-an-xsd

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you found the Altova suite of tools.  Those are great, but they're not free.

There are a couple of ways to go about this, that I can think of.

1. There's [jsons2xsd](https://github.com/ethlo/jsons2xsd) - note, I have not used that, so I can't say anything about it; but it looks like the lib is under active development, which is good.
2. A possible roundabout way of getting your XSD is to start with a json doc (not the jsonschema) that's pretty complete and conformant to your jsonschema, use any of a [multitude](https://www.google.com/search?q=json%20to%20xml%20online) of [json to xml](https://jsonformatter.org/json-to-xml) [converter](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-to-xml-converter.html)s, and convert your [xml to xsd](https://www.google.com/search?q=xml%20to%20xsd%20online) ([one such tool here](https://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html)).

Hope that helps.